# How to flex-wrap from the bottom of the container up?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I want to add a varying number of divs to a container, and have them align to 'gravity', as in the bottom row fills up first, then the next row, and the top row may be incomplete.
it's basically a reverse of the standard flex-wrap, but I don't seem to be able to find how to do it.

I'm doing:
`display: flex;`
`flex-wrap: wrap;`
`align-content: flex-end;`

but the incomplete row is still on the bottom.

Is javascript going to be necessary?

Any pointers appreciated :-)

Comment: show code and a plus for codepen or something similar or a minimal reproducible code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `wrap-reverse` instead of `wrap`.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  gap: 20px;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</section>
```